# How to refresh cart if there is no product left?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

I need to refresh my cart page everytime, when products.length is 0 but I can't figure out how to write that if condition, now it writes unreachable code.
I think it is something simple, so I am here to ask.

```
 switch (action.type){ 
     case "REMOVE_PRODUCT":
      return products.filter((p) => p.id !== action.productId);
      if (products.length === 0) {
        window.location.reload();
      }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you code is unreachable since it is after a `return` statement, so change it to something like this:

```
switch (action.type) { 
  case "REMOVE_PRODUCT":
    const data = products.filter((p) => p.id !== action.productId);
    if (data.length === 0) {
      window.location.reload();
    }
    return data;
}
```

**Note:** If you are using `redux`, as it seems, maybe is better to handle this logic in the component that uses the data instead of here.

Comment: this `case` might work, but there is a return within the `case` block and the linters would complain.

Comment: Check the edit, it has basically the same outcome but with no linter issues, or at least it should not.

Comment: I would "call" this `case` from an effect or something like: `useEffect(() => { if (!products.length) dispatch({type: 'REMOVE_PRODUCT'}); }, [products.length]);`

Comment: Nicely done, this looks perfect

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving `code unreachable` as you are returning before checking into the **IF** block.